# Finding an item in a collection in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains the following data:

```
1390 resource core\scripts\script.properties
1395 resource core\scripts\script.xml
1396 resource core\scripts\script_customer.xml
...
```

and so on.

I also have a list of args, e.g. `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc.

What I'd like to do is to extract the numeric id, if exists, by given file name.

I wrote the following to read the contents of a file into a collection:

```
$regex = "^(?<code>\d+)\s+(?<descriptor>\w+)\s+(?<filename>.*)$"

$results = Get-Content .\resources.txt |
   ForEach-Object {
      if ($_ -match $regex) {$matches} else { return }
   } | 
   select –Property @{name='code';       expression={$_.code} },
                    @{name='descriptor'; expression={$_.descriptor} },
                    @{name='filename';   expression={$_.filename} }
```

Which gives me all the entries from the file in a nice list.

How can I now query the `$results`, to give me the `code` for any entry that contains the filename in args?

e.g. in C# LINQ, I'd do something like:

```
from arg in args
from result in results
where result.fileName.Contains(arg)
select result.code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (PSv3+):

`$results | where-object filename -match $arg | select-object -expand code`